# Symfony Query in controller

Tags: mysql, symfony, model-view-controller

```
$query = $em->query("
    SELECT c.id AS id
    FROM collectif c, zone z
    WHERE
        c.zone_id = z.id
    AND z.label = '$zone'
    ANDc.collectif = '$collectif'
");

$c = $query->fetchAll();
$idc = $c['id'];
```

I have this query that returns a single line, Symfony shows me an error as what variable id undefined

NB: I know that's don't respect the concept of Symfony [MVC] but it's for a particular reason so if someone can tell me how I can resolve this problem

Thank you

Comment: `$idc = $c[0]['id'];` ?

Comment: Very curious what your "particular reason" is. It's probably your real problem for which you should be asking a question on how to resolve it.

Comment: It's not to show a bad example that I specify here that it's a particular reason, I used a request in a controller

Comment: `z.label = '$zone' and c.collectif = '$collectif'` - please don't do this.  please create parameters and set them on your query...it will be a lot safer that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query->fetchAll()` should return numeric array of elements so key `id` does not exists. You should try `$c[0]['id']` to get value.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather use the results in the assocative way, you can use `fetchAssoc()` instead:

```
$c = $query->fetchAssoc();
$idc = $c['id'];
```

Here is the documentation for reference:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#fetchassoc

I'm just giving an alternate way to do this.

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: No, it did not work, the solution is : $query->fetchAll();$c[0]['id'];

Comment: But as per your original post you wanted to use `$c['id']`, so in that case if you use `fetchAssoc(0)` instead, then you can use `$c['id']` like I've indicated in my answer. I use `fetchAssoc()` exactly in this way, so I know it works. I was only trying to provide you with a better solution.